# To unlink npm link without installation

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-link

Currently I am working on multi-module UI project, where each module need to build using npm plugins (like `copy`, `concate`, `grunt` etc).

Now as there were large number of modules, and to build each module , it requires download of `node_modules` packages locally, which takes lot of time, what I did is just downloaded globally from parent package.

But still on building sub-modules, its throwing error packages not found locally (like `grunt` not found locally etc), so to solve this issue, I created symlink using npm link command in each module, which creates local `node_modules` dir in each module and just working fine.

But main issue after building each module, I need to unlink there packages in `node_modules`. 
If I am using command: `npm unlink <pkg>`, then it is unstalling `pkg` globally , making pkg dir empty, which is what I don't want. I just need to unlink from sub-modules but NOT uninstall globally.
I googled out, but I just find npm unlink as solution.
Even if I am deleting the `node_modules` dir from sub-modules, it is also deleting it globally.
Any solution.